# Python subprocess on Linux: no such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am trying to get the install location of conda. This works fine on Windows:

```
conda_path = subprocess.check_output('where anaconda').decode("utf-8").strip()
```

In a linux shell `whereis conda` works. `os.system("whereis conda")` returns zero.

However,

```
conda_path = subprocess.check_output('where anaconda').decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Fails with: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'whereis conda': 'whereis conda'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're executing `where`, not `whereis`.

Comment: Also, it should be `['where', 'anaconda']` if you're not going to use `shell=True`

Comment: But you shouldn't be using `subprocess` at all for a PATH lookup, not with `where` or `which` or `whereis` or anything else. Python has built-in tools to do that itself.

Comment: Specifically, you should be using [`shutil.which`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.which).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a single string, you need a shell to parse it into the command name and its arguments: `subprocess.check_output('where anaconda', shell=True)....`

Otherwise, you need to provide a *list* where the command name and each argument is a separate element. (One of the primary jobs of a shell is to do precisely that parsing.)

```
conda_path = subprocess.check_output(['where', 'anaconda']).decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: Duplicate covers this, no?

Comment: In passing. That one seems to requires `shell=True` for more than just splitting the command string. Ideally, there's a duplicate that focuses on just the splitting.